# Repeat Case Functions Used to Transpose

Tags: sql-server

With the help from another poster, I developed the following code:

```
Select a.[PT_FIN]
  ,[RESULT_DT_TM1] = max(case when RN=1 then [RESULT_DT_TM] end)
  ,[Weight1]       = max(case when RN=1 then [WEIGHT_RESULT] end)
  ,[Sysbp1]        = max(case when RN=1 then [SYSBP_RESULT] end)
  ,[DiaBP1]        = max(case when RN=1 then [DIABP_RESULT] end)
  ,[Temp1]         = max(case when RN=1 then [TEMPERATURE_RESULT] end)
  ,[Oxy1]          = max(case when RN=1 then [OXYGEN_SAT_RESULT] end)
  ,[Fio1]          = max(case when RN=1 then [FIO2_RESULT] end)
  ,[Flow1]          = max(case when RN=1 then [Flow_Rate_Result] end)

  ,[RESULT_DT_TM2] = max(case when RN=1 then [RESULT_DT_TM] end)
  ,[Weight2]       = max(case when RN=1 then [Weight] end)
  ,[Sysbp2]        = max(case when RN=1 then [Sysbp] end)
  ,[DiaBP2]        = max(case when RN=1 then [DiaBP] end)
  ,[Temp2]         = max(case when RN=1 then [TEMPERATURE_RESULT] end)
  ,[Oxy2]          = max(case when RN=1 then [OXYGEN_SAT_RESULT] end)
  ,[Fio2]          = max(case when RN=1 then [FIO2_RESULT] end)
  ,[Flow2]          = max(case when RN=1 then [Flow_Rate_Result] end)
```

ETC

Each number at the end of the variable corresponds to a row a subject may have data (some subjects have 1 row of data, some may have 10). Is there an efficient way to repeat this code to capture a max of 10 rows of data so I do not have to add for example:

```
 [RESULT_DT_TM3]= max(case when RN=3 then [RESULT_DT_TM] end)
 [Weight3]= max(case when RN=3 then [WEIGHT_RESULT] end)

 [RESULT_DT_TM4] = max(case when RN=4 then [RESULT_DT_TM] end)
 [Weight4]= max(case when RN=4 then [Weight_Result] end) 
 ....
```

Comment: *"Is there an efficient way to repeat this code"* = No. You are doomed to this type of complexity because of how you store the data (using many columns instead of using many rows), you could "unpivot" your table first, then "pivot" for presentation. Would need sample data.